# Passing attributes from Backbone model to Spring Controller as arguments

Tags: javascript, spring, backbone.js, spring-boot

I have a form where users can input their own arguments for a graphing program. The submit function is definitely saving the model, but when I go to the output page, I get an error that says "There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'null' not supported".

I'm using a backbone model to save these arguments, so here is my model:

```
var GraphModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "graphTitle": "",
        "prefix": "",
        "inputFile": "",
        "grType": ""
    }
});
```

The submit event in the view stores the user values in those attributes. It then goes to a new page, "/output". The submit function in my view looks like this...

```
submit: function( event ){
var model = new GraphModel();

model.set({graphTitle: $( "#graphTitle" ).val(), prefix: $( "#prefix" ).val(), 
    inputFile: $( "#inputFile" ).val(), grType: $( "#grType" ).val()});

var graphTitle = model.get("graphTitle");
var prefix = model.get("prefix");
var inputFile = model.get("inputFile");
var grType = model.get("grType");

model.save();

console.log(graphTitle + " " + prefix + " " + inputFile + " " + grType);

window.location = "http://localhost:8181/output"
}
```

I'm trying to input the graph arguments as the model attributes, which are passed in as

```
public OntologyGraph(String graphTitle, String prefix, String grType, 
    String inputFile) throws Exception {
```

I then have my controller code, which I'm just trying to use to return a JSON format right now to test it.

```
@RestController
public class GraphController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/output", consumes = "application/json", 
            produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody OntologyGraph graph(@RequestBody OntologyGraph model) 
            throws Exception {

        return model;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start of you seem to have forgotten the Request Method

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/output", consumes = "application/json", 
            produces = "application/json",method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public @ResponseBody OntologyGraph graph(@RequestBody OntologyGraph model) 
            throws Exception {

        return model;
}
```

Notice I've put 2 Both POST and GET but you can put one too like this

```
method=RequestMethod.GET
```

However if your problem persists try specifying the media type or content to backbone like this :

```
myModel.fetch({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

or

```
myModel.save({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Hope it helps